# JavaScript - Replace the values of a Nested Object, without affecting the whole object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

**The Problem:**
I have this function. Which removes all KeyValue Pairs that have an `Empty String` as value from a Payload.

The problem is, that I want to apply it in an Object that is Nested. Not the whole Payload Object. Example:

```
configuration: {
  conf1: "",
  conf2: "Something",
  conf3: ""
},
resourceName: "Name"
```

In this case I want to apply my UtilityFunction, in the configurationObject. Which would result in this:

```
configuration: {
  conf2: "Something",
},
resourceName: "Name"
```

So, I used a few Methods. `Object.assign`, `rest`, in order to supply an object with all the outside parameters, but also, the output of the utility applied to just the configuration object.

I tried:

```
Object.assign(formValues, removeEmptyKeysUtil(formValues.configuration));
// Results in printing the values in the main object.
```

Also:

```
{ formValues, ...removeEmptyKeysUtil(formValues.configuration) };
// which does not do anything
```

Can you please help me, and explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `stripEmptyStrings` function takes the original `object` and the `target` key. 
this function can also handle if the target property of the object is `""` and will delete that property regardless of if it is an Object or not.

```js
const stripEmptyStrings = (object, target) => {
  const _target = object[target];
  
  if (_target === "") {
    delete object[target]
    return object;
  }
  else if (typeof _target === "object") {
    Object.keys(_target).forEach((k) => {
      if (_target[k] === "") delete _target[k];
    })
  }
  
  return {
    ...object,
    [target]: _target,
  }
}

const obj1 = {
  configuration: {
    conf1: "",
    conf2: "Something",
    conf3: ""
  },
  resourceName: "Name",
}
const result1 = stripEmptyStrings(obj1, "configuration");
console.log(result1)

const obj2 = {
  removeMe: "",
  resourceName: "Name2",
}
const result2 = stripEmptyStrings(obj2, "removeMe");
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: Your answer is quite correct. But I found another option. You see the function should be generic enough. As it is used in multiple places. Also, the Data are Dynamic, which would add another degree of difficulty. I used the following after a lot of trial and error:

 `Object.assign({}, formValues, {
        configuration: removeEmptyKeysUtil(formValues.configuration)
      })`
Which seems to work perfectly, and it can be used as a ref to even more nested object, in the future. Thanks for your time.